# Nuget with Artifactory. Key not valid for use in specified state

Tags: nuget, artifactory, nuget-package-restore

I am using Artifactory as NuGet repository to store all the nuget packages. 
 When we use this Artifactory link as source, the package Manager in Visual Studio prompts for credentials and worked very fine.
 As soon as we moved to build machine (with out VS) and try to build application it is throwing error :

> .nuget\NuGet.targets(100,9): error : Key not valid for use in
>   specified state.

I added source with -user -password and put config at local user location. I tried with ClearText password and encrypted password both are throwing same error.

Am I missing anything here? Please advice.

Answer (score 13):

I believe the error isn't related to Artifactory.
The issue NuGet reports is related with encrypting/decrypting user credentials in nuget.config files.

I encountered the error when I tried to set apiKey for a repo:

```
NuGet setapikey user:pwd -Config .\NuGet.test.Config -Source .\packages
```

NuGet reported "Key not valid for use in specified state". 
I had NuGet.config file located near NuGet.test.Config. That nuget.config contained `packageSourceCredentials` section with credentials of other user (than one which was passed to setapikey). 
After I remove that credentials from nuget.config the error gone.

Comment: Yes: The error essentially indicates that the credential stored in the config file could not be decrypted correctly. This means that when the credentials were stored they may have been done under the context of a different user than one which is trying to run the build. A work around would be to remove the NuGet source from the Nuget config file and then re-add it by logging in as the same user which will be running the build.

Comment: Or, if it is some super-secured server, one can use the `-StorePasswordInClearText` argument of `-configfile %ProgramFiles(x86)%\NuGet\Config\NuGet.Config` and just store the password as is.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same error when I logged into Windows using a new user account (story: our network admin at our company had removed our users due to an infection by a ransomware and created a new user account for each of us).

We have a local nuget server at our company (created using free Nuget Server).

As @Jinsoo stated, I needed to remove the nuget settings in Nuget.Config (at %AppData%/Roaming/Nuget folder) and set again the apikey for our nuget source using such a command:

```
nuget setApiKey abcdefghijklmn -Source http://www.our-company-nuget-server.com/nuget
```

After that I was able again to issue 'nuget push' commands.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `NuGet setapikey` encrypts the credentials using the currently-logged-on-user's private key. Therefore, only that user can use these encrypted credentials. If a different user (a service account for CI/CD etc.) tries, they get `Key not valid for use in specified state`.

Answer (score 1):

Please check Nuget.Config in %AppData%\NuGet
You may want re-create it in order to resolve the issue.

FYI, I had the same problem with my build agent, the issue is resolved by removing "nuget.config" in "C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\NuGet"

Comment: I solved the same issue, by removing an existing source (' nuget Sources remove  -Name <myname> -Source http://<mysource/repository/xxx-nuget' ) and adding it back (' nuget Sources add -Name <myname> -Source http://<mysource/repository/xxx-nuget')

Answer (score 0):

Got this issue in TeamCity after adding a global nuget config to the build servers.

Had to change to a **newer version of nuget.exe** in the build configs, as the old version probably could not cope with some setting in the nuget config.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. 
For me the problem could be resolved by simply putting a **dotnet restore** task **in front** of the **dotnet build** task. 
In the dotnet restore task I could then specify my feed. With just the dotnet build task it tried to restore nugets with the NuGet.conf file and the local logins, which is more error prone.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to Artifactory.

NuGet *setapikey* **in Windows** encrypts the PASSWORD using
**Protected Data** with currently-logged-on-user's context. So issues related to authentication as above come about because of two reasons:

1. The user who created the nuget.config file is not the same with the user trying to use it in a build or other action.
2. The file was created in a **Windows** machine and used (CI/CD for example) in a **Linux** machine. **Linux** doesn't have  **Protected Data** capabilities and therefore it can not decrypt the password even if the user is the same. To preserve compatibility between OSes create the nuget.config file usin the flag *--store-password-in-clear-text*.